# Highcharts ColumnRange - Display time range on yAxsis instead of Date

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have highchart issue  . Currently it disaplys Months on yAxsis as variable but in my arraylist [you can find it in jsfiddle]  there is a variable called `time duration` which is normal `hh:mm:ss` format . I want to display this on yAxis and let the bars display on this format .

Here is my jsfiddle

[jsfiddle example..](http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/16/)

Comment: You can use formatter which you have commented (http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/19/) but the problem is that in your chart you have quite big range (many days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue .  All I changed is  I assigned `"from": 1` for all the varialbes data in arraylist and it starts from bottom of the chart till to reach to the end point `to:...`

[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/21/)

Thanks